# How to add checkbox to the given dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to insert checkbox for dropdown displayed in the image but I am unable to find a solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdrNP.png)

Comment: Hey Kumar, what do you mean, select and checkbox are two different types of form-input. How you want to insert and what did you try?

Comment: You will have to put your code here (stackoverflow code snippet/fiddle) rather than image. Please.

Comment: How unfortunate - I cannot insert a checkbox in the dropdown in the image, either :p Please, read how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask